# "Objects are not valid as a React child" Redux error when conditionally connecting a component?

Tags: react-redux

I'm attempting to load a component with Redux only when the environmental variable `USE_MOCK_PROPS` is set to false. If it's `true` then I'll render the component without Redux but with some mock props instead.

```
import React from "react";
import Page from "./page";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const { USE_MOCK_PROPS } = process.env;

const mockProps = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

export default function() {
  if (USE_MOCK_PROPS) {
    return <Page {...mockProps} />;
  }
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      state
    };
  };
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Page);
}
```

The non-Redux part is working fine however when trying to use Redux I get this error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent, displayName}). If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import Page from "./page";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const { USE_MOCK_PROPS } = process.env;

const mockProps = {
  foo: 'bar'
}

function mockedComponent() {
  return <Page {...mockProps} />;
}

function connectedComponent() {
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      state
    };
  };
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Page)
}

export default USE_MOCK_PROPS ? mockedComponent : connectedComponent()
```